# $E_{\infty}$ algebra in characteristic zero

Tags: category-theory, homotopy-theory, operads

Let $A^{\bullet}$ be a cosimplicial commutative algebra over a field $\Bbbk$. Denote with $N(A)^{\bullet}$ the conormalized Moore complex. Since $A^{\bullet}$ is equipped with a product, the Alexander–Whitney map induces an associative product
$$\Delta : N(A)^{\bullet}\otimes N(A)^{\bullet}\to N(A)^{\bullet}.$$
which is commutative in cohomology.

If $A$ is good enough, the product above may be interpreted as a piece of some complicated operads $P$ (Eilenberg–Zilber operad, or Barratt–Eccles operad). In particular they are a cofibrant replacement of the operad $\mathsf{Comm}$, and  they induce an $E_{\infty}$ structure on $N(A)^{\bullet}$ (see [cochain on a simplicial set](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/cochain+on+a+simplicial+set)). It seems to me that these two operads are defined in order to find an $E_{\infty}$ structure on $N(A)^{\bullet}$, when the characteristic of the field is positive (so the hard case).

> My question is: what happens for characteristic zero? Are there some simpler $E_{\infty}$ structure on $N(A)^{\bullet}$?

Here a suggestion: $(N(A)^{\bullet}, \Delta)$ is a differential associative algebra, where the product is graded commutative in cohomology. Is that an $E_{\infty}$ algebra?

Comment: In the general case I believe the smallest known  $E_\infty$ suboperad of Eilenberg-Zilber is the McClure-Smith (also known as the sequence operad, which is a quotient of the Barratt-Eccles). Finding small interesting suboperads, perhaps over various rings, is, as far as I know, an interesting open problem.

Comment: [Asked and answered on MO.](http://mathoverflow.net/q/226333/36146) (In the future, make sure that you point out when you crosspost, and maybe wait a while before you do it... It prevents duplicating efforts.)